# Silverstripe CMS multiple "success" messages

Tags: php, silverstripe, cloudways

I'm having this issue on my production server but not in local development:

Loading any page of the CMS (excluding secondary tabs) fires off a "success" notification, sometimes 5-6+ of them at the same time. I can not seem to track down where they're even coming from let alone what's causing them. I'm at such a loss I feel like I'm even having a tough time explaining it so I'll attach a screenshot.

Server is Cloudways PHP stack: 1GB RAM, Apache/Nginx

[image: CMS success message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an issue that was already fixed. See this [issue on github](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/5281).

It only happens on SSL/HTTP2 servers, so that explains why you don't get this issue on your local dev environment.

You should be able to solve your problem by updating the CMS.

Comment: Beers for you @bummzack Upgrading 3.1.13 => 3.4 did the trick. Thank you